# Migration from Joomla

Tags: 7, feeds, migrations

I am going to start work on a website that is already developed in Joomla 1.5
What are the possible ways to migrate the contents from Joomla.

PS: I have looked into joomla module but no luck!

Any ideas will highly be appreciated!

Comment: I have also used a sandbox module joomla2drupal which is based on migration but it is not working either

Answer (score 8):

I've used [Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) and [Menu Export/Import](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_import) to migrate Joomla sites to Drupal a few times. It's a little tedious but it works.

I think the next time I have to migrate  Joomla site to Drupal I will use the [Joomla to Drupal module](https://www.drupal.org/project/joomla). It doesn't appear to be regularly updated but looks like it should work for Joomla 1.5 and less. I don't think it will be useful for Joomla 2.x and up though.

Comment: Do I need to have joomla site setup on my local machine or we can migrate it from remote site as well - @awasson

Comment: If you use the Joomla to Drupal module, you can migrate from Joomla from a different server but the Drupal site needs to be able to access the Joomla database and file system (to copy the files).

Comment: I am using the same module, I can't access the file path as I don't have ftp. I have used ninja explorer plugin in joomla to find configuration and db info.
http://i.imgur.com/UDuEZqU.png
How can I find path of Joomla installation

Answer (score 6):

You can use [Migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate) module which provides a flexible framework for migrating content into Drupal.

There is one GitHub project available at [piyuesh23/joomla_drupal](https://github.com/piyuesh23/joomla_drupal) which has already some Drupal classes to migrate Joomla into Drupal.

For more technical details, check [Joomla related Issues for Migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/migrate?text=joomla&status=All) or example code of [migrating images, setting url, alt, title in prepareRow](https://www.drupal.org/node/2359479).

---

If you'd like to avoid coding classes, alternatively check [Joomla to Drupal module](https://www.drupal.org/project/joomla) or [XJoomla at GitHub](https://github.com/rfilipo/XJoomla).