# Joomla to Drupal: how to use migrate module

Tags: migrations

I want to move my website from joomla to drupal. I read that the [**migrate**](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate) module is the appropriate but i don't know how to use it. Can someone give guides to do this.

Comment: This thread seems like a good starting point http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/135035/migration-from-joomla

Answer (score 1):

Use [**Joomla to Drupal**](https://www.drupal.org/project/joomla) Module

> This module enables the import of the following content from a Joomla
>   website into Drupal.
>
> - Users
> - Sections & Categories into Taxonomy Vocabularies and Terms
> - Content items to nodes

If you want to use [Migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate) module, Here is the link [Getting started with Migrate](https://www.drupal.org/node/1006982)